# calling the next item in my array

Tags: javascript, arrays

right now I have an array of videos.  How do I make it so when i click next and prev the next or previous video in the array loads.

```
 <video id="video" controls autoplay width="1000">
  <source src="videos/test.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="videos/test.ogv" />
 </video>

<a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap(vidURL[i+]); return false;">next</a>



<script>
var vidURL=["videos/test.ogv","videos/test2.ogv","videos/test3.ogv","videos/test4.ogv","videos/test5.ogv"    ]; // literal array
function vidSwap(vidURL) {
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
myVideo.src = vidURL;
myVideo.load();
 myVideo.play();
}
```

Comment: In an onclick attribute, javascript is assumed, so there is no need to preface your function call with `javascript:`. Also I recommend getting started with jQuery if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

Using yout code, it'll be something like this.
What you need to do is have the video that you loaded on a javascript variable.
Then, when you click prev or next you can call a function that will put the correct video number and call it.

```
<script>
var vidURL=["videos/test.ogv","videos/test2.ogv","videos/test3.ogv","videos"]
var video = 0;

function vidSwap() {
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[video];
  myVideo.src = vidURL[video];
  myVideo.load();
  myVideo.play();
}


function prevVideo() {
  if(video == 0) {
    video = vidUrl.length;
  }
  else {
    video -= 1;
  }

  vidSwap();
}

function nextVideo() {
  if(video == length) {
    video = 0;
  }
  else {
    video += 1;
  }

  vidSwap();
}

</script>


 <video id="video" controls autoplay width="1000">
  <source src="videos/test.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
  <source src="videos/test.ogv" />
 </video>

<a href="#" onClick="javascript:prevVideo(); return false;">prev</a>
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:nextVideo(); return false;">next</a>
```

Comment: when I implement this its returning false, do i write <a href="#" onClick="javascript:nextVideo(); return false;">next</a>

Comment: it may have some errors cause I made it by head. See @brpyne response and use my taughts. He says that his code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce variable which will save current video index, then increment it or decrement it each time you press next/prev

```
</script>
var i = 0;
<script>

javascript:vidSwap(vidURL[i++])
```

Comment: this will break when reaching the last array item and press next :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing another plus sign in your increment operator.

**Try changing**

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap(vidURL[i+]); return false;">next</a>
```

**To this**

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:vidSwap(vidURL[i++]); return false;">next</a>
```

Comment: this will break when reaching the last array item.

Comment: This is correct.  I figured you would handle that type of logic after getting through your first problem.  Syntax errors like that can easily be overseen, I've hit my forehead at least a hundred times over stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped up alternative with wrap-around;

```
<a href="#" onClick="return Vids.next();">next</a>
<a href="#" onClick="return Vids.prev();">prev</a>

...

var Vids = (function() {
    var _currentId = -1;
    var _urls = ["videos/test.ogv","videos/test2.ogv","videos/test3.ogv","videos/test4.ogv","videos/test5.ogv"    ]; // literal array
    return {
        next: function() {
            if (++_currentId >= _urls.length)
                _currentId = 0;
             return this.play(_currentId);
        },
        prev: function() {
            if (--_currentId < 0)
                _currentId = _urls.length - 1;
            return this.play(_currentId);
        },
        play: function(id) {
            var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
            myVideo.src = _urls[id];
            myVideo.load();
            myVideo.play();
            return false;
       }
    }
})();
```

Comment: is it possible to put multiple source types in the array